# kth smallest element sorted matrix using QuickSelect

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I know this has been asked before but this question is about my specific code. I am trying to do a psuedo QuickSelect algorithm where I compare k to the midpoint of a sub interval of a sorted matrix.

I keep getting a timeout error.

Here is the matrix:

```
matrix = [
   [ 1,  5,  9],
   [10, 11, 13],
   [12, 13, 15]
],
k = 8
```

Here is my code:

```
def kthSmallest(self, matrix, k):
    """
    :type matrix: List[List[int]]
    :type k: int
    :rtype: int
    """

    return self.matrixRecur(matrix, (0, 0), (len(matrix) - 1, len(matrix[0]) - 1), k)

def matrixRecur(self, splicedMatrix, left, right, k):
    start_row, start_col = left
    end_row, end_col = right
    mid_row = (start_row + end_row)/2
    mid_col = (start_col + end_col)/2

    i = start_row
    j = start_col
    lcount = 0
    while(not (i == mid_row and j == mid_col)):
        if j < len(splicedMatrix[0]):
            j += 1
        else:
            j = 0
            i += 1
        lcount += 1
    if k == lcount:
       return splicedMatrix[mid_row][mid_col]
    elif k < lcount:
        return self.matrixRecur(splicedMatrix, (start_row, start_col), (mid_row, mid_col), k)
    else:
        return self.matrixRecur(splicedMatrix, (mid_row, mid_col + 1), (end_row, end_col), k-lcount)
```

I pass in tuples to `matrixRecur` which contain the `(row, col)` of the endpoints of the interval. So, if I want to search the whole matrix, I pass `(0, 0)` and `(n, n)`. `matrixRecur` will look at a subinterval, determine the midpoint based on the row col numbers of the endpoints, count the number of elements less than the midpoint, compare it to `k`. If `k` is less than the number of elements less than the midpoint (`lcount`), then the kth smallest element is within the left interval because there are at most `lcount` elements less than the midpoint and `k` < `lcount`.

I am running this on an interview question site and the site continues to tell me my code times out. I am not seeing why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above approach will not work. As your matrix is row and column wise sorted. Consider the matrix like below

```
10, 20, 30, 40
15, 25, 35, 45
24, 29, 37, 48
32, 33, 39, 50
```

Your approach will fail in this case. You are getting time out because you are traversing the whole 2D matrix. Worst case time complexity would be `O(mn)` (m and n are respectively number of rows and columns).

You can use a **min-heap** to solve this problem.

Algorithm:

```
1. Build a min heap of first row elements. A heap entry also stores row number and column number.

2. for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
       Get minimum element (or root) from min heap.
       Find row number and column number of the minimum element.
       Replace root with the next element from same column and min-heapify the root.

3. Return the last extracted root.
```

Time complexity : `O(n + kLogn)`

Source : [Kth smallest in 2D matrix](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallest-element-in-a-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-2d-array-set-1/)

Comment: I saw that solution. i was just wondering if it was possible to solve with binary search. i know it is. thanks for the help. also I think the reason I was getting time out for the above matrix is because my midvalue is not computed correctly.